# In Assembly language (LC 2200 MIPS), Coding Confusion

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline, processor

If I were to increment $a0 from 0 to 10 using a loop. Then, increment memory address 0 from 0 to 10 using a loop...

Would the code roughly look like

```
Loop:
addi $a0,1
```

Comment: No. That's one instruction.

Comment: you have not looped yet, and you have not compared to see when to loop back or keep going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you implement loops in MIPS Assembly:

```
.globl main

main:
# start of the loop
loop:
    bgt $a0,10,exit # checks if $a0 is greater than 10 loop ending condition
    addi $a0,$a0,1  # adds one to the $a0 the loop variable
    j loop          # jumps to continue loop

exit:
    li $v0,10       # sets the value of $v0 to 10 to terminate the program
    syscall         # terminate
```

Kindly [check this link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/loop.html) if you want to learn more about loops in MIPS Assembly

Comment: Since you know the loop runs at least once, you'd normally use `loop: addiu $a0, $a0, 1` / `ble $a0, 10, loop`.  (Ignoring branch-delay slots here.)  2 instructions are better than 3.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)